# SAS-sgplot-add label to bar clusters

Tags: sas, visualization

I am looking for an option to add label to bar clusters.

I want the values: 0.940, 0.250, 0.520, 0.580, and 0.230 in the middle of the clustered bars, like the following:
[image]

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?  If 9.4, what maintenance release - 9.4m7?

Comment: @Joe I ca see it's 9.4ver, but I don't know where can I see the maintenance release

Comment: `proc product_status;run;` Information will be in the log about your version.

Comment: I think I have 9.4M6

Comment: When you say middle, I am not sure if I understood you right.  Do you mean in the middle of the bar?  Or do you mean on top still, but in the space between the bars?

Comment: @Joe in the middle of the clustered bars. Please see the updated picture.

Comment: @Joe Plus, the values above the bars come from another variable

Comment: Okay; that is a bit more clear.  My first part of my answer is irrelevant, then, but the second part is probably the right approach.  Please edit your question with example data and example code that produces as much as you can of the above, and I can show you how to add in the needed parts to get to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have SAS 9.4 TS1M2 or later, you have an option, `seglabel`, which specifically does this, other than the 'display only once', which I don't think is a thing you can get out of the box.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.cars;
vbar cylinders/group=origin  groupdisplay=cluster seglabel;
run;
```

If you don't, or you need more control than that gives you (such as your request to display only once), there are options, such as in my [paper, Labelling without the hassle](https://github.com/snoopy369/presentations/blob/master/Labelling%20without%20the%20Hassle/MWSUG-2014-DV04.pdf); it is for stacked bar charts, but the general approach would work for clustered also, you'd just have to adjust things some.

This gets somewhat close, and probably would get nearly perfect for your case; it needs some customization for groups that don't have all three group values present, but you don't have that in your example.

More complex solutions exist using annotations or GTL, as well, with this general approach (of overlaying on the precomputed bars a label).

```
proc summary data=sashelp.cars;
class origin cylinders;
types origin*cylinders;
var mpg_city;
output out=cars_summary(drop=_:) n(mpg_city)=count;
run;

data cars_labels;
  set cars_summary;
  if origin='Asia' then count_asia=count;
  if origin='USA' then count_usa=count;
  if origin='Europe' then count_eu=count;
  
  ypos = floor(count/2);
run;

proc sgplot data=cars_labels;
vbarparm category=cylinders response=count/group=origin groupdisplay=cluster;
scatter x=cylinders y=ypos/markerchar=count_asia discreteoffset=-0.35;
scatter x=cylinders y=ypos/markerchar=count_usa discreteoffset=0.20;
scatter x=cylinders y=ypos/markerchar=count_eu discreteoffset=-0.1;

run;
```